# Unable to access list elements in Django Webpage

Tags: python, django, chart.js

Following is the context dictionary that I am passing I am rendering to my webpage

```
    context = {'subdivision_selected': str(subdivision_selected),
               'labels': keep_month_names_only(list(rainfall_data[0].keys())),
               'data': new_dict}
    data = {'2011': [26.9, 84.8, 72.8, 111.4, 326.5, 383.2, 583.2, 441.5, 757.1, 212.3, 150.8, 238.5],
            '2012': [119.9, 45.6, 30.9, 55.8, 533.9, 458.2, 317.3, 369.6, 868.9, 209.7, 300.5, 187.3],
            '2013': [67.1, 37.6, 43.0, 46.3, 509.3, 777.0, 564.8, 336.7, 473.6, 455.8, 354.2, 92.3],
            '2014': [41.9, 8.6, 0.0, 11.1, 238.0, 416.6, 467.6, 321.6, 412.9, 402.6, 201.2, 100.4]}
```

After passing the context I am accessing the same from Django Webpage using chart.js as shown in following code

```
{% for a in data %}
var ctx = document.getElementById({{  a  }}).getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [{% for i in labels %}"{{ i }}",{% endfor %}],
        datasets: [{
            label: '{{  subdivision_selected  }}  {{  a  }}',
            data: {{  data.a  }},
        }]
    },
});
{% endfor %}
```

When i try to access following line, it returns empty and blank page is seen

```
    data: {{  data.a  }},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looping though a dict, you want to use this syntax to access the data:

`{%for key, value in data%}
  var key = {{key}}, var value = {{value}}
{%endfor%}`